# iOS AVPlayer never gets ready

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am using this code to start playing local video chunks referenced to form a play list.

The very same code works on one project, but not on another.
On the project I am working on right now, I can see how the first chunk gets loaded, and the first frame also show up. But the `AVPlayer` never start playing because it never gets the `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` notification:

```
- (void)loadAssetAsync
{
    NSLog(@"loadAssetAsync for URL: %@", videoURL);

    /**
     * Create an asset for inspection of a resource referenced by a given URL.
     * Load the values for the asset keys "tracks", "playable".
     */
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];

    NSArray *requestedKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kTracksKey, kPlayableKey, nil];

    // Tells the asset to load the values of any of the specified keys that are not already loaded.
    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler:
     ^{
         dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                            // IMPORTANT: Must dispatch to main queue in order to operate on the AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem.
                            [self prepareToPlayAsset:asset withKeys:requestedKeys];

                        });
     }];
}
/**
 * Invoked at the completion of the loading of the values for all keys on the asset that required.
 */
- (void)prepareToPlayAsset:(AVURLAsset *)asset withKeys:(NSArray *)requestedKeys
{
    //assert([NSThread isMainThread]);

    // Make sure that the value of each key has loaded successfully.
    for (NSString *thisKey in requestedKeys)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVKeyValueStatus keyStatus = [asset statusOfValueForKey:thisKey error:&error];
        if (keyStatus == AVKeyValueStatusFailed)
        {
            BVLogWarn(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, error.localizedDescription);

            [self handleErrorForProxy:error];

            [self assetFailedToPrepareForPlayback];
            return;
        }
    }

    if (!asset.playable)
    {
        BVLogWarn(@"%@: Item cannot be played", THIS_FILE);

        [self handleErrorForProxy:nil];

        [self assetFailedToPrepareForPlayback];
        return;
    }

    // Create a new instance of AVPlayerItem from the now successfully loaded AVAsset.
    playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

    // Observe the player item "status" key to determine when it is ready to play.
    [playerItem addObserver:self
                 forKeyPath:kStatusKey
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                    context:BVPlayerItemStatusObserverContext];

    [playerItem addObserver:self
                 forKeyPath:kBufferEmpty
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                    context:BVPLayerBufferEmptyObserverContext];

    [playerItem addObserver:self
                 forKeyPath:kLikelyToKeepUp
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                    context:BVPlayerLikelyToKeepUpObserverContext];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:playerItem];


    // Get a new AVPlayer initialized to play the specified player item.
    player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    // Do nothing if the item has finished playing
    [player setActionAtItemEnd:AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone];

    /* Observe the AVPlayer "currentItem" property to find out when any
     AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem: replacement will/did
     occur.*/
    [player addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:kCurrentItemKey
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:BVCurrentItemObserverContext];

    // Observe the AVPlayer "rate" property to update the scrubber control.
    [player addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:kRateKey
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:BVRateObserverContext];

    [player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*) keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary*)change
                       context:(void*)context
{
    // AVPlayerItem "status" property value observer.
    if (context == BVPlayerItemStatusObserverContext)
    {
        AVPlayerStatus status = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
        switch (status)
        {
            case AVPlayerStatusUnknown:
            {
                [self removeTimeObserver];

                [self syncTimeScrubber];

                [timeControl setEnabled:NO];
                [playButton setEnabled:NO];
                [fullscreenButton setEnabled:NO];

                [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
            }
                break;

            case AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay:
            {

                if (firstPlayback|becomeActive)
                {
                    [timeControl setEnabled:YES];
                    [playButton setEnabled:YES];
                    [fullscreenButton setEnabled:YES];
                    [upperControls setHidden:NO];
                    [lowerControls setHidden:NO];
                    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];

                    if (firstPlayback) {
                        [playbackView setNeedsDisplay];
                    }

                    if (self.shouldAutoplay)
                        [player play];

                    if (firstPlayback) {
                        timeRemaining.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", timeStringForSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(playerItem.duration) )];
                    }

                    firstPlayback = NO;
                    controlsHidden = NO;

                    if (!isSeeking)
                        [self startHideControlsTimer];

                }

                if (becomeActive) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(lastTimeStop, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                           toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero
                            toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero
                         completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
                             if (finished && rateToRestoreAfterScrubbing)
                             {
                                 [player setRate:rateToRestoreAfterScrubbing];
                                 rateToRestoreAfterScrubbing = 0.f;
                             }
                             [self addTimeObserver];
                             [playbackView setPlayer:player];
                             becomeActive = NO;
                         }];
                    });

                }else{
                    [self addTimeObserver];
                }
            }
                break;

            case AVPlayerStatusFailed:
            {
                AVPlayerItem *thePlayerItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
                BVLogWarn(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, thePlayerItem.error.localizedDescription);

                [self handleErrorForProxy:thePlayerItem.error];

                [self assetFailedToPrepareForPlayback];
            }
                break;
        }
    }
    // AVPlayer "rate" property value observer.
    else if (context == BVRateObserverContext)
    {
        [self updatePlayPauseButton];
    }
    // AVPlayer "currentItem" buffer is empty observer
    else if (context == BVPLayerBufferEmptyObserverContext)
    {
        [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
    }
    // AVPlayer "currentItem" is likely to keep up observer
    else if (context == BVPlayerLikelyToKeepUpObserverContext)
    {
        [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
    // AVPlayer "currentItem" property observer.
    else if (context == BVCurrentItemObserverContext)
    {
        AVPlayerItem *newPlayerItem = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

        // New player item null?
        if (newPlayerItem == (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            [playButton setEnabled:NO];
            [timeControl setEnabled:NO];

        } else  // Replacement of player currentItem has occurred
        {

            if (!becomeActive) {
                [playbackView setPlayer:player];
            }else{

            }


            [playbackView setVideoFillMode:[self scalingMode]];

            [self updatePlayPauseButton];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: I am having a similar problem, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: The problems was that the viewController was always being set to nil. Difficult to explain. But at the end, it had nothing to do with the player itself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put some log before your if ? Maybe the notification is working but it's stucked because your if?

```
case AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay:
{
  NSLog(@"NOTIFICATION TEST PASSED");
  if (firstPlayback|becomeActive) {}
}
```

Comment: And what about AVPlayerStatusFailed? This is working correct?

Comment: No it never fails actually

Comment: Maybe you should try to put there incorrect filename or something so you can see if the problem is in whole notification system or is just question of AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay.

Comment: Agree, the player status can be `AVPlayerStatusFailed`, `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` or `AVPlayerStatusUnknown`. Put some breakpoints there and see if you reach them. It would also help us help you if you minimize the code in your original question to the absolutely minimal that reproduces the problem